# JDBC Insertion Issue

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

So I have a doPost method in an order checkout servlet which checks the value of a 'commit' parameter and is supposed to insert an order record into the database if the parameter is true, and then forwards to an order page.

However, the insert isn't executed for some reason; yet the forwarding to the order page works. And I know my SQL syntax is correct because I can insert a record within the doGet method in the order page's controller. (but this causes some undesirable issues)

Anyone understand the issue here?

Comment: Also worth knowing is what database and driver you're using and any transaction information.  My hunch is that autocommit mode is off and the transaction is not being committed.

Comment: @NateTheGreat is probably right. If the connection's autocommit is off (and it is by default), then you will need to `connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);` and then `connection.commit();`

Comment: It was an issue with my form direction; woops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are geting the value of the commit used for get mime type, such as queryString. Becuase of that you are not getting the value of commit. Can you please check and change the code.